# Second HDD not booting Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, kernel, hard-drive

I have 2 HDDs. Both have 2 partitions. I have XP installed in the first HDD, and I installed 12.04 into second HDD by freeing half space of second partition of that HDD through "Something Else" option in LiveCD. I created all the Ubuntu partitions as logical, so that half of it has Ubuntu installed, and the rest half is accessible through XP.

Installation worked fine, and it asked for restart. I changed the boot order to second HDD, and it gives me `NTLDR not found error CTRL+ALT+SHIFT to restart` error. I then inserted LiveCD, and tried to boot through it. After sometime, `Kernel Panic: vfs: Not Syncing` error. I can't boot into Ubuntu in any way. Help please.

Comment: Can you boot from Second hard drive ( Ubuntu installed) via `Boot Menu` options through BIOS

Comment: No. Whenever I try to boot from the second HDD (Ubuntu installed), some "NTLDR error" is displayed, and I have then no choice but to restart the system. It says: NTLDR is missing. Press **CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart**

Comment: Try the answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/48516/63025 from live cd

Comment: I've tried booting from the LiveCD, but it then gives me `Kernel Panic` error, and the Caps Lock and Scroll Lock lights starts flashing. It's like I'm completely cut off from ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the alternative to this problem.

I first booted into XP, and through `Components` services, I freed the memory allocated to Ubuntu, and reallocated it to the partition to which it belonged.

I then Booted into Ubuntu LiveCD, and selected `Install Alongside Windows.` After that, Ubuntu installer automatically selected the Second HDD in which I previously installed it. Then I allocated the desired space for Ubuntu and successfully installed.

Then I restarted, gone into `Boot Menu` and made **Hard Drive the 1st boot device, and the Second HDD as Primary Boot Drive.** then I booted into XP and found that the Space allocated to Ubuntu was from the very Partition which I was trying to take.

Unfortunately, the Manual Partition didn't worked out for me, but this alternative got me XP and Ubuntu installed in two different Drives just the way I wanted. Anyways, thanks for all your support.