# Unable to update Ubuntu because /root is too small

Tags: partitioning

I have 14.04 LTS and when it was installed there were three partitions it looks like from Gparted.

1. Is `/dev/sda1` which is the `/root`
2. Is `/dev/sda2` which is Extended and does not show anything for mount. (the size is the total drive size which is 1.8Tb)
3. Is `/dev/sda5` which is `lvm2/pv` and mounted as `ubuntu-vg` (this also shows as 1.82Tb but also shows 1.82Tib used.

When I look at the graphical display it shows the root as 256 mb over all three partitions. I think I need to expand that but how?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have /boot instead of /root on sda1?

Comment: Most likely, and then you may well have a bunch of kernels taking up all space. If that is the case: http://askubuntu.com/a/509545/289138

Comment: you'd better also include output for `df -hT`

Comment: `/root` is the home directory of the root user.  The root directory is simply `/`.

Comment: It's almost certainly `/boot`, and definitely not `/root`, that's too small. I believe you're seeing [bug #1357093.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1357093) Please use the link to indicate the bug affects you and add a comment describing your experiences.  Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clear off some of the older kernels. [More complicated commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142926/cant-upgrade-due-to-low-disk-space-on-boot) may be necessary in some cases.