# Ubuntu 14.04 will not boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

I went to start my laptop and it will not boot the operating system. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and is the only OS on the laptop. It has been installed on there for over a year. Regular updates have been carried out (but none were carried out the last time it was successfully used). When powering on the laptop the following happens:

1. Normal Packard Bell/Bios splash screen displayed
2. A screen presenting me with the option of starting Ubuntu or a memeory test, defaulting to Ubuntu after 30 seconds (I don't normally get this screen?) - I select Ubuntu
3. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCsuj.jpg) is what appears on the screen and I get stuck there

Comment: Did you install any new drivers etc.?

Comment: The memtest and Ubuntu thing is GRUB. It's Ubuntu bootloader, it's very normal if it appears. Also, that image = kernel panic! Try installing a different kernel, i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That screen means you are having a kernel panic and it is likely during your system last update something went wrong with the kernel. it probably didn't generated initram-disk correctly and therefore the kernel goes into panic mode during boot.

If you were just typing a few words from your screenshot you will find plenty post where people had similar issues as yourself.

Here is one of the posts for example on this same forum:

```
  http://askubuntu.com/questions/509514/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-boot
```

you can follow the instruction and restore back your system.

If you encounter any troubles you can post your queries here again then we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now fixed. Very much appreciate your help.