# Ubuntu server 14.4 not booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, server

After uninstalling gnome desktop,My ubuntu server not booting.I am getting the following error.

[image]

I am new in ubuntu.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the gnome-desktop is not a good idea without installing the unity desktop.

As a normal procedure you have to run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity` to install the Unity desktop and then remove the gnome-desktop.

Now your machine is in kernel panic mode and to recover from it follow the below steps.

Go and take a look in to the below URL to boot the machine in the recovery mode

[How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Once you are in shell install the unity desktop using the below provided command.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity
```

Comment: this will also shown same error

Comment: Aer you able to login to shell? I recommend that you take a look in to the below URL
http://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0

Comment: No @jaison,I tried with repair cd,After that i backup files and re installed the OS

Comment: I am using raid ,may be that was the problem

Comment: I have worked on software raid not on hardware raid, hope this below url help you in configuring raid properly.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/587194/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... ;-)