# Kernel Panic block (2,0)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, uefi

This is my first question here and I'm trying to give as much information as possible:
I tried dualbooting Linux Ubuntu (first Gnome then regular Ubuntu) with windows 8 on my Lenovo U310 Ideapad. I also disabled UEFI SecureBoot and tried to install ubuntu. First I had a problem with the grub download and then I tried to format my partitions in the UI. I beleave that then did I make some serious mistake which resulted in the error. Also I used an usb stick formated with the universal usb installer from pendrivelinux.

Now if I try to boot following error occurs:
"Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS unable to mount root fs on unknown block (2,0).

I don't really care about dual booting anymore, I am just happy if ubuntu could start working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0

Comment: Hi @MichaelLindman I would have marked this as duplicate if it were not because, as luck would have it, I am using the same model at work. None of the answers in the duplicate link worked (They are also very old and might not take into consideration the whole UEFI thing). Still many thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Fair point. So is there a specific problem with dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu on this hardware?

Comment: The issues I had here were: 1. The one the OP is suffering from which landed me on the link you provided. I also would have provided that link if not for the chance of having the same HW. 2. UEFI setting was not very friendly in booting the USB drive. I also want to mention this exact thing happens on the IdeaPad Z50 and Z510-70. Basically you either have "luck" and it works or you don't. A Firmware upgrade did not help. So to avoid spending hours or in my case 4 days on it, bye bye windows But again, many thanks for pointing it out, this could have been lost for anybody with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

since Windows 8 is not on your plans (and from what I could read in your question, I think it is not working anymore), only Ubuntu, my suggestions for your specific hardware which I also happen to have are the following taking into consideration that you have made a backup of everything you need from the hard drive and that Windows 8 does not matter. So with this in mind, we can continue (This was the last resort I had to do with this specific laptop):

1. Go to the BIOS / UEFI Settings and disable SecureBoot, UEFI and set the BIOS to be legacy mode. Ubuntu can still be installed with SecureBoot/UEFI enabled but we are simplifying the whole chaotic installation procedure here. Also check any additional settings and make sure they are on default (Like avoiding tuning anything).
2. Insert the Ubuntu Live USB (Does not matter if it was made with pendrivelinux, USB Creator or anything else, if it boots and it gets to the Ubuntu Live USB Desktop then you are OK. Also, when booting the USB, select the MemTest option to check for memory problems.
3. When the Ubuntu Live USB Desktop appears (By simply selecting "Try Ubuntu before installing"), open Dash and run GPARTED. We are going to go all the way with the hard drive.
4. When GPARTED opens, delete the whole drive. Simply delete it. Remove all partitions and make sure we are starting from scratch. After everything is deleted and GPARTED says everything is OK, close GPARTED and open the Ubuntu installer.
5. Follow the whole Ubuntu installing procedure (Your option to choose either automatic partitioning or doing it manually)

It should work now without any problems. Let me know how it went please.