# Grub rescue after udpating to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on another computer running Ubuntu 14.04 from a bootable USB stick. During the installation I chose not to delete the existing files, but only to remove Ubuntu 14.04 and install Ubuntu 16.04. I got a warning message telling me to create a partition with at least 1 Mb and a specific name (which now I don't rembember). Quite stupidly, I ignored that message and continued the installation. The installation was succesfully completed, but now I can boot from neither the USB stick nor the hard drive.

If I try to boot *without the USB stick*, I get

> error: file not found
>   grub rescue>

I tried to follow [this page](http://www.easytechguides.com/error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue.html) and I have the following situation.

> grub rescue> ls
>   (hd0) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1)

I set

> grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub
>   grub rescue> set root=hd0,gpt3

because only with this choice I get a meaningful answer to

> grub rescue> ls /

(in all other cases I get "error: unknown filesystem"). If I now type "insmod normal" I get

> grub rescue> insmod normal
>   error: file not found.

Here I am stuck and don't know what to do. Note that I also tried to run insmod normal on all other partitions (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition)), but without success.

If I try to boot *from the USB stick*, I get a screen of incomprehensible messages, and I can't do anything. The last two are

> [    1.074641] Kernel Offset: disabled
>   [    1.074664] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs in unknown-block(0,0)

Any help would be appreciated. PS: I don't care if I lose any data, I just want my computer to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and hassle free solution is to install ubuntu again and do a wipe, since you said you not necessarily need to access data on this machine.

Comment: Yes, but how? I can't boot from the USB stick.

Comment: Have you any machine you can recreate the stick on? sound like you forgot to create the EFI partition for ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean, recreate? Should I format the USB stick, make it bootable and try again?

Comment: Exact this is what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, I can. I'll do it, but I don't think I've made any changes to the USB stick after I used it to install Ubuntu 16.04. :/

Comment: mhmmm i have not much knowledge about EFI boot to be honest, maybe a bios setting to clean the HDD again or explicitly start only from usb ? if you not made changes to the stick it makes no sense to recreate it.

Comment: (Thanks for your help!) What is a "bios setting to clean the HDD"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of a user that has now deleted his answer, I could find a solution: my USB stick was somehow corrupted, so I recreated the bootable USB stick and reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 (this time making a complete wipe).

After I recreated the USB stick, I didn't get the kernel panic error message (see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592213/setup-error-end-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unk?rq=1)).

Comment: Well then i can undelete my answer. i deleted it because i thought it was of no use.