# Installing ubuntu 15.04 on my compaq cq-41 laptop

Tags: boot, 15.04, bios

I downloaded ubuntu 15.04 and burnt it onto a DVD. While booting from the disc, a warning message came up. I tried same disc on another laptop, and it worked. My one run ubuntu 14.10 well.

What do I do?

[image]

Comment: The image u will find at http://i.stack.imgur.com/aKXFR.jpg

Comment: Please edit rather than adding info with a comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISK 15.04 + Laptop other = works
DISK 15.04 + Laptop yours = not working.

Is your laptop still have 14.04? can you run upgrade from it?

If not, any spare HDD to swap and test it? maybe HDD problem?

I usually just reinstall it...

Or if you can clone the system.
1) laptop other 's 15.04 works, right.
2) if you have a external hdd case, then 
a) put your HDD into this external hdd case
b) assuming you have a DVD/USB 15.04 drive, boot laptop other with it.
c) run gparted or you may need to sudo apt-get install gparted.
d) run gparted, and then copy the "other laptop" OS partition into your external HDD. 
e) after copying/cloning, make sure in gparted, you modified the flag as "boot".
f) put the external HDD's HDD back to your laptop and boot.
g) if not booting, then boot from USB/DVD OS image again.
-> google search boot-repair and follow instruction to install boot-repair. and choose recommended setting. it should fix it for you/

I hope one day ubuntu will put these tools in the release by default.

Comment: i upgrade to 15.04 from 14.10 and it works.karnel is 3.19.0.21 . hdd works well.no problem . using samsung ssd 128gb