# Kernel panic (…) Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel

I have upgraded from `Ubuntu 14.04` to `16.04.01` after that there is a problem with grub2 (I have upgraded by `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`), I am getting an error message: `Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`.

I have tried:

- `sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)` and `sudo update grub2` (I've got an error: `Missing /lib/modules/$(uname -r)` and `could not open directory /lib/modules/$(uname -r)`).
- Boot repair disk (but it keep saying that "`Please close all your package managers (Software Center, Update...`".
- [lsblk -f](https://justpaste.it/y2tf)
- [Output: Boot Info Script](https://justpaste.it/y1jg)

Like "Julie Pelletier" noticed "/ was on /dev/sda1 during installation" but my root partition appears to be /dev/sdb1".

But I am not a pro, and i would be grateful if someone told me how to use "mount" (or initramfs) in order to fix this. Answers in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0) post didn't help (I'm not even sure if I should use partition on `sda` or `sdb` in this line `sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt`)