# Kernel Panic: VFS cannot open root device or unknown block error -6

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, kde

Note that this is Kubuntu (KDE Ubuntu)

I've been having a problem for a while where if I turn on the computer, it just takes me to a black screen. It sticks there with no output and no hint of what's going on except that the Caps Lock indicator light on my keyboard flashes on and off (weird, right?)

If I then turn off the computer (by holding down the power button for a few seconds), and turn it back on, I get a boot menu where I can choose 'Advanced options for Ubuntu', and that lists different versions, recovery modes, some of which work just fine.

That's what I've bee doing for the two weeks or so I've had this problem, and it worked until just now. The alternative options only booted me into the command line. I was able to fix this with [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/377594/how-to-start-plasma-desktop-from-ssh-console-on-desktop-session), so now I'm typing this from my desktop.

I'm reluctant to turn off the computer in case it happens again, and I'd like to just tear out the root of the problem.

Screenshot of error:
[image]

Comment: Caps lock blinking is a sign of kernel panic -- fatal crash of the Linux that runs Ubuntu. Try opening `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor as root and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash debug --verbose"`. That way you can see exactly what's causing the panic during boot. Then run in terminal `sudo update-grub` and shut it off. When you turn it back on you should see messages about everything the kernel is doing. See what errors you get just before the crash.

Comment: Something about mounting the filesystem: https://imgur.com/VvPLO88

Answer (score 7):

It seems someone has been able to solve this issue here

[Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

They suggest running

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
```

Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: `$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

`update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-version`

`WARNING: missing /lib/modules/version`

`Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!`

`depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed version`

`depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed version`

`gzip: stdout: No space left on device`

`E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1`

`update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-version with 1.`

Comment: According to [update-initramfs manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-initramfs.8.html) `version` is `"the  specific kernel version for whom the initramfs will be generated.   For  example  the  output  of  uname  -r  for  your currently running kernel."` I've updated my post. You should use the version of kernel that will be running your KUbuntu. It looks something like `3.5.0-47-generic`. Also, it is telling you `No space left on device.` So the partition that holds your Linux images might be out of space.

Comment: @Grund - That means your boot partition is full.

Comment: Just to inform anyone who stumbles upon this answer: If doing this doesn't help, try completely reinstalling the kernel. That fixed it for me.