# Kernel panic after failed attempt to update kernel

Tags: kernel, 18.04, initramfs

[image]
Yesterday my system got stuck while using the apt upgrade. I had to force reboot using the hardware button. Now while booting after passing the crypto setup it fails to open and opens a initramfs console. 
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Booting through old kernels gives the same.

Comment: Can you boot using an older kernel by selecting "Advance Options for Ubuntu" in boot menu?

Comment: No not able to that. Same happens with any kernel I select.

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer to a similar question helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/988672/867819

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel panic and unable to boot Ubuntu 16.04 after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898449/kernel-panic-and-unable-to-boot-ubuntu-16-04-after-updating)