# Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task! Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: boot, kernel

I had this problem after a regular package update; when it finished it asked me to reboot and while it was turning off it didn't reboot, so I forced the shut down and boot it up again, and then this showed up

[image: kernel panic]

What should I do to fix this issue? I've tried to fix it following this thread [Kernel panic and unable to boot Ubuntu 16.04 after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898449/kernel-panic-and-unable-to-boot-ubuntu-16-04-after-updating) but as the nature of the issue is different it didn't work, so I don't know what to do. I'm running the previous kernel version as it still works.

Comment: It's possibly a broken package version dependency. What does `sudo sh -c "apt update && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove && apt autoclean"` error out on?

Comment: In the worst case that you can't find a proper solution, report a bug against the new kernel,  and keep using the older one until there is a new version that doesn't crash.

Comment: @SHawarden I've tried the command you mention, it looked like there weren't errors besides some sources it couldn't connect to. Also I didn't mention but every time I reboot, it freezes on the purple screen, so I have to re reboot it to launch properly.

Comment: Are those sources ubuntu related or random additions of your own?

Comment: @SHawarden the source that I've found last time I run the command was this https://launchpad.net/~marutter wich I guess is ubuntu related. Also I run again the command today and a new error log appeared "E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
" I haven't do any changes since last time y posted. Also I've found in another forum the same issue reported on linux mint https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=294177 apparently there isn't a way to solve it yet

Comment: That error is fairly explicit. The system is doing something in the background or you Ctrl-C'd something before it released the lock. `ps awux | grep "apt\|dpkg"` should show it. I'd recommend disabling non Canonical sourced apt repos. You can find any apps installed using `synaptic`'s Origin section. Disable anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as well as any 3rd party additions to `/etc/apt/sources.list` then re-run `sudo sh -c "apt update && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove && apt autoclean"` to make sure nothing is locking down a kernel dependency to the wrong version.

Comment: @SHawarden I've checked, and re run the code to update and there was no trouble updating, the run didn't show any error on the log this time, and the initramfs of the kernel version 4.15.0-50 were instaled, but after rebooting the computer the issue stills the same, the kernel panic and the need to re reboot each time.