# Upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS caused kernel panic. “Fixing” the problem “works” – but this does not solve the problem for good!

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, kernel, 22.04, initramfs

Until a few days ago, I was running `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` and accidentally pressed <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`Alt`</kbd> + <kbd>`F6`</kbd>. This made my screen turn black and I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120296/used-ctrl-alt-f6-in-linux-and-cant-get-my-screen-back). I do not know how I fixed the problem but I managed to get back to Ubuntu and continue my work. But this key combination seemed to have damaged something on the `/dev/sda5` partition.

When I restarted the computer, I got a `BusyBox` screen with an `initframs` prompt that wanted me to manually run an `fsck` command in order to fix `/dev/sda5`. (I am using a dual-boot system: Ubuntu as the primary operating system and Windows 10 Professional 64 bit as the secondary operating system. Windows is located on `/dev/sda4`.) So, I ran `fsck /dev/sda5` and typed `y` every time I was asked if something should be fixed. When the process was finished, I tried writing `reboot` but that did not work. So, I typed `exit` and `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` started working but it was slower than usually.

I then finally upgraded my Ubuntu version from `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` to `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`. At first, everything seemed to work quite well but the new version of Ubuntu tended to be slow as well. When I restarted the computer, problems arose again. This time, I got a kernel panic like this:

```
[    0.106049] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.106049] RETBleed:WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!
[    0.370778] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/responses buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.370790] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/responses buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.483021] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.483111] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu
[    0.483179] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GL62M 7REX/MS-16J9, BIOS E16J9IMS.31C 10/24/2017
[    0.483261] Call Trace:
[    0.483301]  <TASK>
[    0.483322]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
[    0.483363]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
[    0.483401]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
[    0.483433]  panic+0x149/0x321
[    0.483467]  mount_block_root+0x144/0x1dd
[    0.483506]  mount_root+0x10c/0x11c
[    0.483539]  prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x191
[    0.483576]  kernel_init_freeable+0x18c/0x1b5
[    0.483616]  ? rest_init+0x100/0x100
[    0.483651]  kernel_init+0x1b/0x150
[    0.483685]  ? rest_init+0x100/0x100
[    0.483719]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[    0.483758]  </TASK>
[    0.483842] Kernel Offset: 0x29a00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    0.483926] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

But even after the kernel panic appeared, I was able to restart the computer, run `fsck /dev/dsa5` **again** and `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` started working as before (in a more or less usable state considering its speed when it came to applications like, for example, Firefox).

I then found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898449/kernel-panic-and-unable-to-boot-ubuntu-16-04-after-updating) but I am not able to reproduce the steps of [answer 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/898459/845469) nor the steps described in [answer 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/988672/845469).

When I restarted the computer again, the computer seemed to try to boot Ubuntu but failed. So, it then tried to boot Windows but Windows wanted to repair files in order to boot. However, Windows also failed to do that. Then, I restarted my computer again an pressed <kbd>`F11`</kbd> which enabled me to get to the `GNU GRUB Version 2.06`. It offered me the option to start Ubuntu in recovery mode. When I opened this option, I was able to choose from four options:

1. `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-47-generic`
2. `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-47-generic (recovery mode)`
3. `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-125-generic`
4. `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-125-generic (recovery mode)`

I first tried to pick option 4 but that did not work. (As far as I know, a kernel panic appeared **again** when I tried to do this (but I am not sure anymore if that was the case).) When I restarted the computer, I picked option 1 and got the following screen:

```
[    0.112973] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.448809] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/responses buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.448826] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/responses buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
/dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Deleted inode 1179964 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initframs)
```

I now ran `fsck /dev/sda5 -y` and got the following output (`...` stands for an omission because the command ran too fast and I was not able to record every output):

```
(initframs) fsck /dev/sda5 -y
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? yes

Inode 4718704 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 4718839 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 4719315 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 4719471 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 4720219 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 4720221 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 4720679 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5506154 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5636869 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5636979 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5637123 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5637124 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5637363 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5637375 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5637686 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 5637696 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 6179120 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6291478 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory struture

...

Free blocks count wrong for group #707 (7156, counted=7164).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #737 (17164, counted=17166).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #754 (22353, counted=22359).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #755 (26341, counted=26370).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #756repair f (15249, counted=15257).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #771 (20213, counted=20234).
Fix? yes

Inode bitmap differences:  -1179964 -4718704 -4718839 -4719315 -4719471 -4720219 -4720221 -4720679 -5506154 -5636869 -5636979 -(5637123--5637124) -5637363 -5637375 -5637696 -6291478
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #144 (5663, counted=5664).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #576 (558, counted=565).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #672 (57, counted=58).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #688 (98, counted=106).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #768 (882, counted=883).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong (5873275, counted=5873293).
Fix? yes

/dev/sda5: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda5: 532851/6406144 files (0.5% non-contagious), 18956397/25600000 blocks
(initframs)
```

Trying to write `reboot` does not do anything. Writing `exit` returns the following output …

```
(initframs) reboot
(initframs) exit
/dev/sda5: clean, 532851/6406144 files, 18956397/25600000 blocks
[ 1276.469780] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[ 1318.592260]
[ 1324.158825] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

… and restarts `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`. *(Do not worry about the high number of seconds. I returned to my computer after about 20 minutes in order to type the commands.)*

**How can I solve the problem for good?** Having such a hassle every time I start my computer cannot be the solution. And Windows has booting problems as well which, in my opinion, are caused by the Linux booting problems I have.

Comment: Switching between consoles (ctrl-alt-f6, ctrl-alt-f1) has no impact on the system. This looks more like broken disk (or windows (anti)virus). Maybe boot from a Ubuntu Live system or something like gparted live usb and look what happens.

Comment: Did you check the hard drive?  And have you installed something in windows to get access on Linux Filesystem?

Comment: Your bios is quiet old. The release notes from MSI of newer BIOS version show "microcode updates", which could be a source of your problem.

Comment: Upgrading the version on a broken system never fixes the problem, Fix the problem and then do an upgrade.

Comment: @Marco Well, I cannot rule out that something with my HDD is wrong. But right now, I can access everything on my HDD without a problem. How should I use something like `GParted`? I also have a USB stick from which I can easily start `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` in recovery mode and access the HDD as well. Also: How can I, under these circumstances, update the BIOS version?

Comment: @nobody How can I, under these circumstances, check the hard drive without corrupting anything? The Linux system has access to all Windows partitions but Windows only has access to the Windows partitions and **not** to the Linux partitions.

Comment: @David Now, it is too late. `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` is already installed and I have to figure out what my current options are and what I can do next.

Comment: You can check it from a live session and backup your personal files.