# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus) installation not working

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am trying to run Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS(32-bit Desktop image) on a Compaq Deskpro. It is running on Windows XP and has Intel Pentium 3.(Quite an old computer)

1) I downloaded the Ubuntu iso file
2) I burned it onto a DVD-R with 4.7 Gigabytes total
3) Restarted the computer and put disk inside
4) It read the bootable disk and loaded a purple screen
5) After the purple screen, it went to a black screen and ran a code automatically then stopped like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54iHT2iyVPDaFhEWHA5YWxJU0k/view?usp=sharing

I tried installing Linux Mint too because I thought it was a problem with Ubuntu but it ended up with a similar screen!

Thanks

Comment: Sorry yes, it is on a DVD-R with 4.7GB.

Comment: Have you tried booting those DVDs in other machines? Have you been able to boot ANYTHING, even a DOS for example, or a system repair utilities disk in the same drive on the same machine? Because the most obvious possibilities that are easy to eliminate is that they are bad disks (possibly because the drive they were burned on is failing) and the possibility that the drive you are trying to boot from is bad. Not saying those are the only things or even the most likely things, but they are easy things to check. When you burned the disks, did you  verify them? Did you check the hashes on the iso?

Comment: I left out an important word. Have you done those things RECENTLY? Disks and drives that were OK, do go bad.

Comment: I burned the iso files on the DVD's from a different computer that is working properly and has burned files without problems before, so I don't think the disks are the problem. I thought that the problem might be something in the computer settings that aren't letting the Ubuntu install. It does start installing, it just stops at the last line of code on the picture.

Comment: Just tried installing Fedora and Lubuntu, and the same thing happened to both. Does anyone know what the screen means? It always pops up after I click install or even when I try without installing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54iHT2iyVPDaFhEWHA5YWxJU0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "Intel Pentium 3.(Quite an old computer)" indicates that you can expect problems with a modern full size linux distro, because the processor lacks some instructions, which are expected to work in order to run. *You can try Wary Puppy*. It might also work with an old Ubuntu or Lubuntu version, but when past end of life, there will be no [security] updates, so it is discouraged. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640

Comment: I have tried Lubuntu and I have ended up with the same result in the picture.

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu? If you tried another (newer) version, I would suggest Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. (You might try 14.04.1 LTS too, but it passed end of life last month, which means that the Lubuntu specific program packages are no longer supported, while the Ubuntu engine under the hood is supported for two more years.) But I suggest that you try some other and ultra light-weight linux distro or try Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS (and run it with a text user interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first,verify your physical machine is fine.

And the cpu is 32bit or 64bit? it facilitate you to download a correct ISO version,it's very important.*Because i have a laptop's cpu is 32bit,and i use the 64bit ISO to install.then the laptop stuck in a purple screen.*

actually,you can use the usb flash disk to burn the ISO image,it's convenient to reproducing bootable disk.

Comment: I actually originally made a bootable disk of the 64-bit version, which said when I started installing it that it was the wrong version for my computer. So I do know that the 32-bit version that I am having the problem with is the right version for my computer.

Comment: did you have a hard disk partition with `ext4` or `ext3`. i saw you picture,and i found the problem:     **VFS:Unable to mount root fs on Unknown-block(0,0) **  (https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)