# Error booting after fresh install - Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 laptop (Dell, trying to dual boot) and am unable to start Ubuntu.  On startup I get the following error:

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Steps I've already taken:

1. Change SATA to ACHI in the BIOS
2. [Run initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)
3. start from the live DVD to check I'm not running out of space in my boot partition

and I still get the same error.

Any thoughts on next steps to solve this issue?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but I looked at that as well - my USB is formatting using FAT32.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Are you using a Windows Software RAID?