# Can't boot into Ubuntu 19.10 after upgrading

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.10

## Can't boot into Ubuntu 19.10 after upgrading

Well, I guess it's finally time to ask for advice on this one.

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my machine but I've run into more errors than I can imagine. I'm going to take you guys to the whole process and hope someone has an idea of what to do.

### Specs

First off, my machine. It's specs are:

`|CPU       |AMD Ryzen 5 1500X @ 3.50GHz      |
|GPU       |NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050 Ti       |
|RAM       |2X4GB DDR4                       |
|MOBO      |ASRock A320M Pro4                |
|DRIVE 1   |3TB Seagate HDD                  |
|DRIVE 2   |250GB Samsung SSD 850            |
|DRIVE 3   |1TB Western Digital HDD          |
|OS        |Windows 10 Home v.1903 (drive 2) |`

Ubuntu 19.10 is installed on drive 1. Secure boot and hibernation are both disabled on the windows installation. CDM support is also disabled on the motherboard so it boots in UEFI mode.

I originally installed it as Ubuntu 19.04 and it's pretty much a default Ubuntu install, there aren't any significant changes I've made to the system.

### Problem

After upgrading to 19.10 the machine can't boot into linux anymore. When the machine is powered it either freezes before it can reach grub. Or it displays the grub menu.  After selecting Ubuntu in the grub menu it displays this error:

[errordefaultoption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqt8x.jpg)

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0) solution. So I select an older kernel. This leads to briefly displaying the error below and continuing into the ubuntu splash screen. This splash screen never completes and I am forced to turn the power off.

[othererror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w9SS.jpg)

There is also another error I found when trying to edit the partitions. When using fdisk it printed this warning `Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary`. It did not seem to be a problem at the time but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? With newer Ryzen chips UEFI update is requried. Was old install UEFI and now new install is BIOS? How you boot install media, is then how it installs. Best to only install in UEFI boot mode. Post this above in your question: `sudo fdisk -lu`

Comment: I had the similar problem, I upgraded like you to 19.10. It would let me get to the log in screen but after that the screen would flash some strange pixelated screen then go black. It did load up properly once but the graphics were severely messed up. any changing/moving graphics were pixelated with dancing multi colored pixels which made it impossible to use. When I restarted the system it wouldn't go past the log in screen and would give me only a black screen. I had to do a fresh install and lost all my data, everything. I'm back to using 19.04.