# Ubuntu stuck on boot in after upgrade to 19.10 from 19.04 in VMware [end kernel panic not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on block (0,0)]

Tags: upgrade, vmware, ubuntu-gnome, system-settings, 19.10

I had Ubuntu 19.04 64 bit virtual machine I upgraded it to 19.10.
After the upgrade finished the virtual machine has stuck on boot in VMware workstation 15. I had used a vmdk image for 19.04 available here
www dot osboxes dot org slash Ubuntu (less than 10 reputation can not post more than 8 links so have to keep it that way)

I made a couple of videos while I was upgrading the virtual machine ( I followed the instructions here www dot liquidweb dot com/kb/troubleshooting-please-install-available-updates-release-upgrading/)
The videos are as follows

Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade messages

Part 1: https://youtu.be/la-kwFYGl14
Part 2: https://youtu.be/U_j-aQRMGW4
Part 3: https://youtu.be/80OPkahASmQ
Part 4: https://youtu.be/nPSo-7daCuQ

Now what could be the problem here as why a fresh upgrade is not able to boot into a system. What should I check in here or do to fix this?
This is a fresh upgrade and what ever kept happening I let it happen.
I logged in to tty6 I get following screenshot.
[image: tty6 screenshot]
I have not restarted the system since the upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 kept happening.

Then while I posted this question here I some how was able to restart the system and now I get

> end kernel panic not syncing :VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown
> block (0,0)

[image: kernel panic unable to mount root on unknown block 0,0]
Here is a video for the same. Now I don't know what should I do. Why this problem came. How to debug this and fix this. Rather than creating a new VM by downloading a new ISO I am more interested to learn and fix the problem which has caused this.

Part 5: https://youtu.be/JhFJEj2dUOM
I seem to have figured out something which might be applicable as mentioned at [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/a/41939) the thing is before upgrading
I did not note down on a paper or pencil as which kernel version was running or to what version the upgrade took place. I have been running defaults only so it should not be a problem. Someone in comments mentioned

> "On my ubuntu 19.10 I've had to run apt install initramfs-tools in
> order to get update-initramfs command –"
> How can I execute these commands given my situation in video 5.

The thing is I do not know how to work with advanced boot menu please see the screenshots and videos I uploaded to understand my situation.
[image: advance boot options]
[image: which kernel to boot in advance options]

Even after booting into one of the kernels in advanced options, I get kernel panic messages.

There is some knowledge gap in my situation I probably have figured out something which I should try but I am not able to understand how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a long struggle I have been able to fix this with the help of previous answers and trial and errors.
I booted into Advanced mode while booting Ubuntu press <kbd>F2</kbd> when you see grub2 bootloader. On some systems you may need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get to advanced boot menu.

In my case since I was in a VMware Workstation environment I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> to get to boot menu as shown below

[image: which kernel to boot]

So now you see many kernels are shown I started selecting one by one.One kernel after other and tried booting in some cases I failed and I got the same error message saying kernel panic vfs unable to mount root filesystem could not find (0,0)

The kernel that worked in my case from above entries was

> 5.0.0-32-generic

The one highlighted in screenshot. I booted it and after I could boot rather than going to GUI or GDM login which will not work.
Switch to a text-based virtual console by pressing (if you are in a virtual machine you may need to press function key on real hardware to get to text based console pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is not required)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> upto <kbd>F12</kbd>
meaning any of these key combination will give you a tty
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Which ever key it gives you a terminal without a GUI press just one of the combinations.
(Just be cautious that in some systems Wi-Fi might get disabled with some function key so leave that combination of function key)
If you are on a real hardware you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ (<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/../../../<kbd>F10</kbd>/) (or whichever key works for you, although usually all will work). The GUI though you will get in either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> depending upon which tty is set for default GUI in your case. Since I am on VMware so I had to press Fn key also other wise you don't need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> just a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>/<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F9</kbd>/<kbd>F10</kbd>/<kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd>
key will give you required command prompt login.
Then login with your username and password. I was logged into tty6 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>)

[image: logged in to tty6]

As explained on answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/48516):

```
update-initramfs -u -k 5.3.0-19-generic (or your version)
```

If you don't know your version. Use:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

And just update Grub:

```
update-grub2
```

But just this grub update won't work as grub still is not there on hard disk.
I am uploading screenshots in my case this command failed also at one or two kernels

[image: generating initramfs]

`dpkg --list | grep linux-image`:
[image: dpkg --list | grep linux-image]

Now without logging in GUI and before a reboot (after doing update-grub2) I did a

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

I got following screenshot during grub upgrade

[image: grub update and re install message]

As mentioned in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/939883/992730
press space to select the desired entry and arrow keys to move up and down.
Now you see even after a `update-grub2` command `dpkg --configure -a` was required.

Now all the broken dependencies or packages which were being upgraded previously and some how had failed in between due to some error restarted from a point where they should have been continuing.

Then after a reboot I was able to get back a working system 19.10

[image: finally working 19.10]

Here I was finally successful.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had the same exact problem. although, I never got the seconds last screen (device selection).

Answer (score 0):

Thx very much for your infos and fix! I ran into the same issue.
For me it also helped to logout from the window manager before the upgrade and go to the console (for example tty6).
Here I started the upgrade process in the command line. After a reboot all worked perfectly.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1188131/edit) your answer by explaining step by step how you managed to solve that issue (add command line for example)