# Unable to boot Ubuntu in dual boot system - Error says kernel panic

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu using a pendrive. Everything worked well the first time after which there was a request to update the system. Once the update happened (don't know what the update was for - I'm a first time Linux user), I'm unable to login to the system. It's a dual boot by the way and the windows 10 works just fine. Please advice. Attached is the pic of the error. [picture of kernel panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VxRp.jpg)

Comment: Looks like this has been solved https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0
I'm unsure of the windows partition but this should give you some steps to take.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

Comment: Thanks to Tejas Lotlikar and Crabtree. Some of the methods involving booting from previous versions did not work for me.  But the one with reinstalling Ubuntu using the FAT32 pendrive worked.   Thank you very much for the support