# update-initramfs - amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs

Tags: boot, kernel, dpkg, initramfs

Ubuntu 18.04 on boot shows the following error:

`Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

Followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/41939/91644) and chose older Kernel from the GRUB menu to login. On running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.15.0-76-generic`, I am getting the following error:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic 
/bin/cpio: 1: /bin/cpio: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string 
/bin/cpio: 1: /bin/cpio: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string 
E: amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs 
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs: 28: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs: /usr/lib/initramfs-tool/bin/busybox: Exec format error
/bin/cpio: 1: /bin/cpio: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string 
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 2 gzip 0 
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic with 1.
```

Following instruction from [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48516/91644), I tried the same using a livecd and got same error as above.

Now I am not even able to login from older Kernel in the GRUB menu. It says `Loading initial ramdisk`

Comment: Change `sudo update-initramfs -u -k version` to `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-76-generic` (this is assuming that 4.15.0-76-generic is your most recent kernel).

Comment: That was symbolic, I actually typed `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.15.0-76-generic`. Changed that in the answer.

Comment: I got that. The command that I wanted you to use had `-c` instead of `-u`. The difference is that I create a brand new fresh file, instead of just updating a possibly corrupt old file. Do this from Recovery Mode via the GRUB menu. Report back.