# Unable to mount root fs on unknown block

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

Currently I am dual-booting Windows along side Ubuntu, but whenever I try to boot Ubuntu it displays the message “Unable to mount root fs on unknown block”. So, I checked the forms, and everyone said to boot to an older version by going through “advanced booting options”, but when I try that I get this message “error: you need to load the kernel first.” How do I fix these issues without the ability to boot into my OS?

Answer (score 0):

Hence your problem is less clarified I will continue on my assumptions.You are missing the initramfs for your usual kernel. If you cannot get to advanced options also, try this.

1. In the GRUB menu select and go into 'Advanced Options'(or something like that).
2. Next select another kernel other than the usual kernel and press `e` to edit.

Then check whether these things are available, if not enter these there.

```
insmod linux
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

and then press `F10`.

You refer to these links also.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first

[Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

Comment: Is this the portion that I need to check for those values? https://imgur.com/a/7NEAOVP

Comment: yes. `insmod linux` is missing put that in and try rebooting.

Comment: At the end of the text?

Comment: try at the end first if it doesn't work try before `linux /vmlinuz ...`. Not that commands after `initrd` and `linux` in my answer can be different from yours.