# Ubuntu 22.04 Kernel Panic - Cannot open root device LVC

Tags: server, kernel, 22.04

Hi there today I tried to update to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04 though after updating have issue with system not starting either via normal or recovery or old kernel version.
[image: Error message]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Boot up using a live USB version of Ubuntu and [use this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48516/167115) to mount the filesystem and then update your initramfs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/a/48516/167115)