# ZFS: kernel panic: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, zfs

I freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I have two Linux kernels in GRUB menu/Advanced options: 5.15.0-43-generic and 5.15.0-46-generic.

By default, it tries to boot the newer one, but that crashes on this error:

> not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

I have to choose the older one to get it start.

My notebook: Dell XPS 9370

I use ZFS with the encryption from Ubuntu installer.

I've tried https://askubuntu.com/a/41939/1623974, but that didn't work for me.

Under `/boot` I have:

1. `initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic`
2. `initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic`
3. and similiar symlinks for `vmlinuz*`

EDIT:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2zhbmp
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2zhbmp
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2zhbmp
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2zhbmp
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

user@computer:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic              5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic              5.15.0-46.49                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.15.0.46.46                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              5.15.0.46.46                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

EDIT2:

I've deleted `5.15.0-46` version, but when I try to do `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade`, it doesn't show any available updates.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Grub will take responsibility to tell which kernel image, initrd image are used to boot. So you need to change the option of grub config in this file "/boot/grub/grub.cfg".

```
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-46-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.15.0-46-generi
c-advanced-6c8f350d-4e7c-4841-98e5-15ca9d43ef32' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio

                ....

                echo    'Loading Linux 5.15.0-46-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=6c8f350d-4e7c-4841-98e5-15ca9d43ef32 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
        }
```

Option `initrd` default not load from your initrd.img, so you need to change initrd name from `initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic` to `initrd.img` .

Hope that will help.

Comment: Firstly, I will have another question: Is it important to use newer versions of Linux kernel? I mean, when I don't get a newer version by `apt dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`, it shouldn't be that important, should it?

Comment: No, it depends on your purpose. Update newer versions for security is the most reason for me to update the Linux kernel.

Comment: And Ubuntu would give me a newer version on `dist/full-upgrade`, right? Because after fresh install I had `x-46-generic`, but I am not getting it with `dist/full-upgrade` now.

Comment: This is out of topic's scope. So please verify if my answer is useful for your case.