# Boot errors (error: out of memory)

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, ram, secure-boot

I’m trying to go back to Linux from windows after some viruses. I was able to download and use the live cd of Ubuntu with no problems (a few messages popped up, but I got no errors once up and running). I could also get through the installation with no problems. But when I try to use Ubuntu, I get “error: out of memory” and the errors listed below.

I get the similar errors when trying another distribution (KDE Neon) - in fact, this one didn’t even make it to the install screen.

I’ve tried with secure boot enabled and disabled, and tried multiple installations with different combinations related to secure boot that comes up during the install process.

Any idea what might be going on? I really need a working computer and I’d rather not go back to windows. I don’t need windows, so any way to get a working Linux system is fine for me. I can temporarily work from the live CE, but that’s not a long term solution.

Thank you so much.

Error log (copied from iPhone text reading function, so there may be a few errors):

```
RE_NOT_FOUND (28218738/psargs-338
1.4442861 ACPI Error:
Aborting method \_SB.PRIB._CPC due to previous error
(RE.NOT _FOUND) (28218738/psparse-529)
1.4443273 ACP! BIOS Érror (bug): Could not resolve sumbol I\_SB.PR88._CPC).
RE.NOT_FOUND (28218738/psargs-338)
1.4443371 RCPI Error: Rborting method \_SB.PR11. _CPC due to previous error
(RE.NOT _FOUND) (28218738/psparse-529)
444385] ACPI BIOS
Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_5B.PR88._CPC1,
RE.NOT_FOUND (28218736/psargs-338)
1.4443951 RCPI Error: Aborting method I_SB.PR12. _CPC due to previous error
(RE._NOT_FOUND) (28218738/psparse-529)
1.444438] ACPI BIOS En ror (bug): Could not resolve sumbol d\SB.PROB._CPCI.
RE._HOT_FOUND
(28218738/psargs-330)
1.4444483 ACPI Error:
Aborting nethod I_SB.PRI3. _CPC due to previous error
(RE._NOT _FOUND) (28218738/psparse-529
1.444498] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve suabol I\SB.PRBB._CPC).
RE._NOT_FOUND (28218738/psargs-330)
1.4445881 RCPI Error: Aborting wethod I_SB.PR14._CPC due to previous error
(RE. NOT _ FOUND) (28218738/psparse-529)
1.4445423 RCPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol I\_SB.PRBB._CPC), RE._NOT_FOUND (28218738/psargs-338)
1.4445523 ACPI Error: Aborting method I_SB.PR15._CPC due to previous error
(RE.NOT _FOUND) (28218738/psparse-529)
1.5549681 Kernel panic - not suncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8.8)
1.5551483 CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: sapper/8 Not tainted 5.15.8-43-generic #46-Ubuntu
1.5553443 Harduare name: GIGABYTE 8/8, BIOS FB85 87/81/2819
1.5554801 Call Trace:
1.5555413
(TRSK>
1.5555961
show_stack+8x52/8x58
1.5556821
1.5557761
dump_stack_1v1+8x4a/8x5f dump_stack+8x18/8x12
1.555868] panic+8x149/8x321
1.555948)
mount_block_root+8x144/8x1d9
1.5568421
mount_root+8x18c/8x118
1.5561383
prepare_nanespace+8x13f/8x1Bd
5562321
kernel-init_freeable+8x18c/8x1b1
5563491
? rest_init+8x188/8x108
5564341
kernel_init+8x1b/8x158
1.5565141
rest_init+8x188/8x188
5566811
ret_fron_fork+8x1f/8x30
5566861
(/TASK>
1.5560151 Kernel Offset: 8/3ae@8888 from Bxffffffff81888880 (relocation range: Bxffffffff88000000-8xffffffffbffrfffr
```

Comment: I’m wondering if it’s related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1842320/comments/125

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product you're trying to use, nor what release.  You can get out-of-memory errors due to invalid ISO  (did you verify it? was it written correctly?  ie. did you perform the validation steps for your *unstated* products), as well as other reasons, but currently you've not provided any specific details as to what you were trying to boot.  I see kernel 5.15 mentioned; but was it an ISO using the GA or HWE stack?  we don't know as not given specific product/release details.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. 

I’m using Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I’ve verified the disk image, but I will try redownloading and burning to another usb just to make sure it’s not a hardware or burning issue. I think it’s the HWE stack (I haven’t made any changes from the default). 

I hope this helps a bit more.

Comment: all the ACPI errors are because your BIOS is reporting invalid data to our kernel. Those are benign and can be ignored if need be. You can get rid off then by disabling acpi but that also means no hibernation and no suspend.

Comment: "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block"  that is more serious and means the kernel was unable to mount the root filesystem. Get to GRUB advanced options and pick an older kernel; that should work.  Happens if you format your system using an alternative filesystem (not ext4 (but there are a few others that do work)) but there are a lot of other reasons.  see https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0 for some methods.