# Ubuntu upgrade to 22.04 with dual boot - Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade, initramfs

I don't have enough reputation to answer any question, so I decided to create a new one to share a solution to my problem.

In my case, I have a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I did an automatic upgrade of my Kubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. Once the process finished, I got the error *"out of memory" error when loading initial ramdisk* that leads to *"Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)" when booting to my Kubuntu partition*.

I followed this thread: *[Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)* without success. They focused mainly in a messy upgrade process, but in fact my problem was with the ESP partition size that was not able to load initramfs. Luckily, my */etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf* was configured to load all the possible modules, so I modified the variable MODULES from **most** to **dep** following this thread: *https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1970402*.

```
MODULES=dep
```

Now, the error disappeared and I can boot normally. Is it possible that during the linux upgrade a new ESP was created? In fact, I created initially a ESP partition with more than 300MB when installing the dual-boot to have enough space. I should have performed manually the upgrade instead of relying on the automatic upgrade...