# Keep getting "end kernel panic - not syncing unable to mount root fs on unknown block"

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I'm trying to run Ubuntu on VirtualBox (on Windows 11). I followed the instructions here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#1-overview

When I press "Start", I get to this GRUB boot menu screen giving me 4 options instead of the login screen shown in the tutorial. The top 2 options always result in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3pw4.png) black screen.

[image: this]

[image: this]

If I press 'c', I get to this screen.

[image: this]

I've seen posts saying what commands to run, but grub doesn't know those commands (e.g. sudo, update-initramfs, apt, get, install; as `sudo update-initramfs -u -k version` is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0#:%7E:text=You%20are%20missing%20the%20initramfs%20for%20that%20kernel.,version%20string%20such%20as%204.15.0-36-generic%29%20then%20sudo%20update-grub.))

Additional fixes I've tried: uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox, deleting and redownloading Ubuntu 22.04.

What's even more annoying is that I've tried pressing "expert" mode when setting up a new virtual machine, and now every time I press "new" I get stuck in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXiWP.png) screen; there's no next/finish or cancel button.

[image: this]

The only thing I didn't follow in the tutorial is I limited the VM to 10 GB instead of the recommended 25 GB, but now I can't even try 25 GB because expert mode is stuck (even after uninstalling & reinstalling VirtualBox).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be solved by allocating the full recommended 25 GB, although I hope it doesn't end up using that much space on my computer.

I was able to get expert mode working by pressing enter while in a textbox (although it still has major glitches if I try to move the window).