Unable to Boot Ubuntu 22.04 with Kernel 6.8.0-45 (Kernel Panic) – Removal Fails with dpkg Error
I have tried the solution from this thread: How to upgrade VirtualBox 6.1.38 to 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04?
but for me I couldn't proceed further after first step: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
I’m facing an issue with my dual-boot setup of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows on a Dell Inspiron 15-3567. The system has been working fine until recently when I noticed that Ubuntu fails to boot with kernel 6.8.0-45-generic. It gets stuck on a blank screen and eventually throws the following error:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 1 PID: 1 comm: swapper/0 not tainted 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 15-3567/04YVDP, BIOS 2.9.0 01/17/2019
What I’ve tried so far:
Updating GRUB using sudo update-grub after booting into 6.8.0-40-generic — No change.
Reinstalling the problematic kernel (6.8.0-45-generic) throws an error:
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic: amd64.
Attempting to remove the kernel using both apt and dpkg --purge results in dependency problems. When I try to fix it using:
Additional Info:
The kernel panic error specifically occurs with 6.8.0-45-generic. Booting into 6.8.0-40-generic works without any issues.
I’ve tried cleaning up old packages and running sudo apt autoremove, but the problem persists.
I would appreciate any suggestions for fixing this issue or removing the problematic kernel cleanly. Is there a way to forcefully purge the kernel without breaking the system?

Try some of the solutions described in the answers at the following link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0 (I like the look of Ondra solution.)

I had a very similar problem on upgrading kernel to 6.8.0-47 from 6.8.0-45 in that resulted in me getting a black screen. This is on a Dell Latitude E6520 with an Nvidia graphics chip. Forced rebooting then gave me the attached screenshot.

I have got around this issue for now by removing the kernel as best described here, but obviously I will have to update/upgrade something one day.
At least it has got me working again.

In my case, removing the 6.8.0-45-generic kernel resolved the issue for now, but like you mentioned, I'm concerned that a future update or upgrade might bring the problem back.
